# where to store my data in appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

lets say we want to do a simple app for android and for this app we want some data. Those data when i test my example on my pc locally i have them in a file with json format. 
lets say that the app doesnt need an internet connection so we cant send a request to a server somewhere.

Now if i move to the android device ( in my case the titanium emulator ) i dont have a server so i can't fetch my json data file.

So whats the secret ? how am i going to do this work ? how all those native apps work with no server, no database, not a way to fetch an xml or json data file ?

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the kitchenSink examples, specifically the FileSystem examples

they will demonstrate how to read and write from the local filesystem of the device

[filesystem.js in KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/platform/filesystem.js)

Answer (score 6):

This page provides examples of three ways to work with local data: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data

- Application Properties
- Filesystem Data
- Local SQLite database

If you specifically want to work with JSON data, this example should be a huge head start for you:
http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data#WorkingwithLocalData-StoringJSobjectsasJSONinproperties

Comment: i was working on smthing else and now i saw ur reply, thx a lot i'll check them !!

Answer (score 1):

as i see, i think you want to save some data locally right?

actually for me, i keep some simple information in the Ti.App.yourdata

such as

---

### win.js

.....
win.name='your name';
Ti.App.name=win.name;

then you can use Ti.App.name for value of win.name anywhere

another way is use [Ti.DB](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Database-module)

that's local db

sorry if it's not answer you question :p im beginner too

Comment: i used an array ...works and for local and simple data seems a nice solution...thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SculeJS](https://github.com/dan-eyles/sculejs), it's a pure JavaScript NoSQL database system designed for use in Titanium, NodeJS, and web based applications. The project is a rewrite of [JSONDB](https://github.com/irlgaming/jsondb-public).